# How to reconnect a socket when catch a SocketException in java?

Tags: java, sockets, reconnect

I've met a problem that when I process my data on my program, that the server may getoff its socket of my client program, but i need to catch this exception and reconnect it to run my program. i did not use the serverSocket but all use the Socket to create an object.
I need your help. the implement code in detail is welcome. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You have to create a new one if you're the client, and just hope the client will do that if you're the server.

Comment: but when i close the old client socket, the jdk notes me that i cannot colse it ? and even when i open a new client socket, how can i get the whole status of the last client socket(both date instream and outstream)? thanks~

Comment: @LillianXiong 'Notes me that I cannot close it' how? And you can't 'get the  whole status of the last client socket'. It's gone. You have to start again.

Answer (score 1):

try to create new one with same ip and port

```
while (!socket.isConnected()) {
                    try {
                        socket = new Socket(inetAddress,  port);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```